# How to get array of values from input using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

Hi I have a view which has a checkbox and the purpose of the checkbox is to filter products according to the brands

My View:

```
 <li>
    <label for="{{$brand->name}}" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
       <input type="checkbox" name="{{$brand->name}}" id="{{$brand->name}}" class="mdl-checkbox__input"  data-value="{{$brand->id}}">
       <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{$brand->name}}</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

When the user clicks on the check box then an ajax call goes

ajax code is below:

```
  $('.filter-data input').on('click',function(){
    var dataValue = $(this).data('value');
    // alert(dataValue);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/brands',
       headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      type: 'post',
      data: {'dataValue': dataValue},
      success: function(data, status) {

         console.log(data.status);
        if(data.status == "ok") {
            // $('..promo-code').append('<span>'+data+'</span>')
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax
});
```

So it make a post request to my controller method in laravel

```
public function listProductsByBrand(Request $request)
{   
    $data = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    die;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I get an array of brand_id when the user checks the corresponding brands from the check box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update your view like:

```
<li>
 <label for="{{$brand->name}}" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
   <input type="checkbox" name="brand_name[]" id="{{$brand->name}}" class="mdl-checkbox__input"  data-value="{{$brand->id}}" value="{{$brand->id}}">
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{$brand->name}}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
```

after that put these line in your ajax code

```
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='brand_name[]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
  });
```

check the value in values variable